# settings.local.yml and settings.yml in the same project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have both `settings.local.yml` and `settings.yml` in the config dir in my rails project. How do I know which one is being used? Or are both being used by my rails project and one takes precedence over the other?

Comment: By convention it should be settings.yml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way a `local` version works is that it takes precedence, or overrides values from a more generic version. That is done e.g in Unix where you might have a `ruby` version in `/usr/local/bin` that is a newer version of the system installed `/usr/bin/ruby` (but you can set your `PATH` so as to break the usual way of doing things)

The same holds for rails configurations: `settings.local.yml` settings overrrule the ones in `settings.yml` (and that might be broken as well). In the railsconfig project  it is documented [this way](https://github.com/railsconfig/config#accessing-the-settings-object):

```
After installing the gem, Settings object will become available globally 
and by default will be compiled from the files listed below. Settings 
defined in files that are lower in the list override settings higher.

config/settings.yml
config/settings/#{environment}.yml
config/environments/#{environment}.yml

config/settings.local.yml
config/settings/#{environment}.local.yml
config/environments/#{environment}.local.yml
```